# Autocad ObjectARX class AcDbGeoPositionMarker coordinate translation

Tags: location, marker, objectarx

How class AcDbGeoPositionMarker translate x,y,z coordinats to lat,lon,elv and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `latLonAlt` method in the AcDbGeoPositionMarker class to get lat, lon and alt. `setLatLonAlt` to set the objects lat, lon and alt. `geoPosition` to get a X, Y and Z coordinates (a AcGePoint3d object with coordinates as properties).

[Link to docs: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACDMAC/2015/ENU/Mac_Lightsaber_Dev_Help/Reference_machtml/index.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=AcDbGeoPositionMarker__AcDbGeoPositionMarker.html](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACDMAC/2015/ENU/Mac_Lightsaber_Dev_Help/Reference_machtml/index.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=AcDbGeoPositionMarker__AcDbGeoPositionMarker.html)